# Insert an HTML element inside the "link_to" erb tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to insert an image above an anchor tag. Everything works great in development, but when I'm deploying to Heroku, the app crashes.

This is the code I'm using:

```html
<ul class="menu icon-top">
 <li>
  <%= link_to 'home' do %>
    <%= image_tag('icons/home', class: "nav-img") %>
    <span>Home</span>      
  <% end %>
 </li>
```

My routes.rb file:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static#home'

  %w[home about_us training recruitment contact].each do |page|
   get page, controller: 'static', action: page
  end

end
```

Heroku crash log (cleaned for better reading):

```html
23: <li>
25: <%= image_tag('icons/home', class: "nav-img") %>
24: <%= link_to 'home' do %>
26: <span>Home</span>
27: <% end %>
28: </li>
FATAL -- : 
FATAL -- : app/views/layouts/_altnav.html.erb:25:in `block in _app_views_layouts__altnav_html_erb__'
app/views/layouts/_altnav.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_layouts__altnav_html_erb__'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__'
```

Comment: Your crash log only has a `<span>` inside the `link_to` but the code has the `image_tag` inside the `link_to` as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, that's what the logs say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make sure relative paths work correctly...

```
<li>
    <%= link_to 'home' do %>
      <%= image_tag('../icons/home', class: "../nav-img") %>
      <span>Home</span>                     
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Also, are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Yes I'm using turbolinks. As it appears, the path to the image was the culprit. Managed to fix it tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it had something to do with the path of the image.
I managed to fix it by replacing

```
<%= image_tag('icons/home', class: "nav-img") %>
```

with

```
<%= image_tag "icons/home.png", class: "nav-img" %>
```

Thank you for the answers.